# Python - notify user every time a loop yields an output Tkinter?

Tags: python, audio, tkinter, window, memory-efficient

I receive API data every 5 minutes and run a Python code to check if the incoming data fulfills certain conditions. The data is in JSON format, but I convert it to a data frame and perform my checks there.
In case one of the checks generates a hit, I'd like to get notified. I'd like to find a fast and resource-preserving way for Python to notify me.

- I think I can't use **"print()"** as I won't be watching Python all the time.
- I could use **"data.to_excel"**, but I'd still have to have a window of my folder open and check manually if a new excel file appears.
- I read that **Tkinter** is widely used to generate a new window so I guess that's the way to go.

What would be the most efficient (minimalistic) code to generate a window (preferably one **with an audio sound when it appears**) with one line of text, e.g. "Condition1/2/3/4 fulfilled, timestamp, string"

Thank you for your kind help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `messagebox` could be very easy.A minimal example:

```
from tkinter import messagebox
import time
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
info = "what"
root.withdraw()
if condition:
    messagebox.showinfo("title",f"Condition-1 fulfilled time:{time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S', time.localtime())} \n info:{info}")
```

if condition is `True`,it will show a small window(it will play the default system sound,and no need to use `winsound.Beep()`).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something even easier than that to help you notify when you got something. You can use the os library to just open the file whenever something gets printed to it. Let's say you use the data.to_excel. Afterwards, you can just open it.
To do that, you can just import os, and the function is os.system(path_of_excel_file). In the path tho you have to be careful and use backslashes for spaces or other special characters.

Comment: I forgot to address the sound part. For that you can print the '\a' character, and that will do a bell sound. If it doesn't work, then it means you have to enable it in the terminal, but i never ran into that problem. Only heard it from others.

Comment: Thx! I used winsound.Beep() because print didn't work.
WRT export, is it faster to export to xlsx or csv or txt?
@GhostyFrosty

Comment: All are just as fast. You can work with each one of them exactly as if you would work with a text file. That is, if your txt file is formatted as a csv (each value is separated with a single comma) you can open it just as easily as a txt, csv, or excel without any trouble, and it will be perfectly interpreted. If you make your operating system open all .csv files with excel, it will work perfectly fine and there are no performance issues. It's all a matter of who opens the file, so that is your preference. For me at least i can open csv's with both notepad and excel without any issue @Dave